# Highlight year value in questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, timestamps, design

When opening a post, some key information I am looking for is the year of the information both in question and answers. I want to know how fresh the information is. Currently the year is written as **'yy**. It is not easy to catch with the eye:

Aug 19 '09 at 23:28

To improve reading, I suggest to highlight the year (and possibly the month) of the date string. This could be easily achieved by playing with the font parameters (size, weight, color, etc.). As a simple example:

**Aug 19 '09** at 23:28

Also using a 4 digit year would increase readability. For example with something like

**2009 Aug** 19th at 23:28

As a workaround, if people are interested, I wrote the following CSS to be used with firefox|chrome and the stylish extension (http://userstyles.org/help/stylish). It uses the element's title which starts by the year, but is not ideal. I wish I could have a different styling for the time stamp.

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com")  { 

.post-signature div.user-action-time a,
.post-signature div.user-action-time  { color: #888 !important;}
.post-signature span.relativetime     { 
   float       : right;
   text-align  : right;
   font-weight : normal !important;
 }
.post-signature span.relativetime:before { 
   content     : attr(title) "\A" !important;
   white-space : pre; /* for the '\A' */
   color       : black;
   font-weight : bold;
   font-size   : 110%;
 }

} /* stackoveflow.com */
```

Comment: I'd argue it is noticeable because only posts from last year or older actually show the year; the display of the year itself is a cue to draw attention.