# How can I check when (date-time) I voted on a particular post?

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, timestamps, timeline

We can check by re-clicking on a vote to see the exact vote time as shown in this image. Actually it's not a feature, but a side effect of voting on a post that has already been locked. :-)

[image]

However, if the post is edited after the vote, then it will simply get unvoted. Neither the hovering of mouse nor the `timeline` shows the date-time.

Is there a standard way which allows us to see the vote timing for a question or an answer?

Comment: People have had some success writing a [UserStyle for the value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152949/282094), with a little modification I can see it working; it's far from "standard".

Comment: @Rob I guess there is a misunderstanding. OP is asking how to see the date without trying to undo the vote which shows the red popup. That userstyle just _reformats_ dates, but is _searching_ one.

Comment: @Tom yup. If they want what's shown in the image it's going to work one way.

Comment: Good idea! I'd personally love to see it in the timeline of the question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any better way than checking the [list of your votes in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote). That list could be quite long ...

[image: screenshot of the "upvote" tab selected, under "votes" in the activity section of the user profile, showing the titles and links of posts that the user has voted on, as well as the date on which the vote was cast]

Comment: Yes, I am aware. But mostly it's impractical, especially for me as I vote a lots of posts. Very time consuming!